# item.text(currenttext+"something") Append to object's text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have:

```
item.text(?);
```

and can set anything I want in it like this:

```
item.text("Lorem Ipsum");
```

But I want to do something like:

```
item.text(item.text+"something");
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Huh? JavaScript and the DOM don't have a `.text()` method. How is `.text()` defined?

Comment: ...you updated to add the jQuery tag. Which means you should be reading the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: I didn't realize it was jQuery until VisioN's answer.

Comment: VisioN was guessing. How do you know he's correct? Why don't you know what code you're using?

Comment: I know he's right, I just wasn't thinking anything through...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `item` is a jQuery-wrapped DOM element, you can do:

```
item.text(item.text() + "something");
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks. I looked all over, but google ignores symbols entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is about jQuery [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method, which can be used so:

```
item.text(function(i, text) {
    return text + "something";
});
```

Of course you can also use `item.text(item.text() + "something")` but this approach is slower than given above.

Comment: Isn't that over-complicated to just append text?

Comment: @Pachonk No, this is the fastest way.